# Android library to render a website in an app

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone, javascript, android-library

I'm trying to create a application which will talk to a database and use a custom web service. But I did hear a year ago or so a library for Android, IOS and Windows mobile which basically allows you to call a website and display the website inside of your application, so it is a browser but there is no navigation or anything special it just uses Javascript (I think). Does anyone have any ideas on what this library is called or do they know of a similar library which would allow my goal to be reached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache Cordova may be your answer, you can check it here : https://cordova.apache.org/